# How to remap keys when using mozc

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus, mozc

I am using a german keyboard, and I applied some stickers to use it also for Japanese input.

The main problem is that the 'ro' key is missing from the right side of the bottom line. So I thought I could just remap another key and put the sticker there, and I changed the layout in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/jp` following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions).

After changing both `<AD12>` and `<LSGT>` to `kana_RO`, I saved the file and tried reloading ibus, reconfiguring xkb, and restarting the PC. There is no xkm file in `/var/lib/xkb`, but nothing seems to work: the keymap is always the same.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to change a mozc or ibus configuration file? Where can I find it?

Output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`:

```
[('xkb', 'de'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp')]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output from this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: I added the output, but I will probably just use anthy instead. It seems that the keymap is compiled into mozc and I don't want to recompile it.

Comment: There is no need to recompile anything. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only XKB layout in the list of input sources is *German*, `ibus-mozc` uses that layout by default, which explains why your modifications of the Japanese layout does not make a difference.

There are two ways to handle it with `ibus-mozc`:

1. You can add the Japanese keyboard layout to your list of input sources and make Japanese the first source in the list, i.e. so the output of the command I asked you to run is changed to:

   ```
   [('xkb', 'jp'), ('xkb', 'de'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp')]
   ```
2. You can edit the `/usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml` file and replace

   ```
   <layout>default</layout>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <layout>jp</layout>
   ```

You mentioned `ibus-anthy`, and one advantage with that input method is that you can control which XKB layout is used in the background via a GUI. OTOH I think that Mozc is preferred over Anthy nowadays by most Japanese speaking users.

Comment: Point 2 is the first thing I tried. without that the keyboard was practically unusable (since German uses QWERTZ instead of QWERTY, many keys were missing or in a different position). Adding the japanese xkb keyboard doesn't change a lot, because my keyboard is missing the key for switching between ascii and kana. Also, if the xkb Japanese keyboard works, I wouldn't need mozc at all I think.
Long story short: I bought a Japanese keyboard on eBay, and I will use anthy in the meantime. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GB: Yes you need a Japanese input method even if the Japanese XKB layout works. And Anthy is fine if that is what you prefer.